# How do I install a perl module in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, perl

I need to use package `List::Compare`. I have downloaded Compare.pm which says

```perl
use List::Compare::Base::_Auxiliary qw(
    _validate_2_seenhashes
    _chart_engine_regular
);
```

What all do I need to install, and how do I install it/them?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to download the file manually, you can install it through APT, Ubuntu's packaging system.

Run this command to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install liblist-compare-perl
```